# Changing the name of a some keys in JSONArray

Tags: java, arrays, json

I have a response from an HTTP request as a JSONArray. There are some keys for values in the json response having names such as `Total_x200_Price` or `Creation_x200_Date` (i.e having "*x200*") instead of each space. So my program cannot find this data. I need to change the keys of such fields to replace the "*x200*" with " " using something like

```
.replaceAll("_x0020_"," ");
```

Is there a clean Java way iterate on the JSON keys and apply this for each key.

> org.json.JSONArray;

i.e my json as follow

```
[
  {name: "selim", Creation_x200_Date: "1/2/2010"},
  {name: "JOhn", Creation_x200_Date: "1/6/2010"}
]
```

I need to apply to every key with such name. I have tried to change to string and back but is too slow? any better ideas

Comment: First iterate over json array and follow [How to rename key in JSONObject using java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29070865/how-to-rename-key-in-jsonobject-using-java)

Answer (score 1):

> So my program cannot find this data.

Replace the string manually is not the solution.

I try to parse this and I got the Output. **Creation_x200_Date** is proper.

see below.

[image: Sample Demo Of parsing your json]

Comment: @Selim Alawwa  Try to parse json as per showing in the image above. If you got your answer, please mark it as answer, as it will be useful for other who has facing same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I think you need. It is creating a new **org.json.JSONArray**. Although, if i am thinking correctly, most probably you would be generating the HTTP Responce JSONArray by using `JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(responceBodyString);` if it is correct then i think replacing the above line with `JSONArray jarr = new JSONArray(responceBodyString.replaceAll("_x200_"," "));` will be more effective.

```
    String jsonString = "[{name: \"selim\", Creation_x200_Date: \"1/2/2010\"}, {name: \"JOhn\", Creation_x200_Date: \"1/6/2010\"}]";
    JSONArray originalJArray = new JSONArray(jsonString);
    JSONArray jsonArrayWithSpaces = new JSONArray();
    for (int i = 0; i < originalJArray.length(); i++)
    {
        JSONObject jobj = originalJArray.getJSONObject(i);
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        Iterator<String> keysItr = jobj.keys();
        JSONObject jobj1 = new JSONObject();
        keysItr.forEachRemaining(new Consumer<String>()
        {
            @Override
            public void accept(String t)
            {
                try
                {
                    jobj1.put(t.replaceAll("_x200_"," "), jobj.get(t));
                }catch (JSONException e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
        );
        jsonArrayWithSpaces.put(jobj1);
    }
    System.out.println(jsonArrayWithSpaces);
```