# org.json.JSONObject : Rename Nested and Listed JSON Keys in Java

Tags: java, json, jackson, gson

I am trying to rename key names in a json object.I can rename at the top level, but unable to rename if the key present inside another object or if it present in a List Object.

This is what i have tried so far.

```
         try {
                jsonObject.put(value, jsonObject.remove(key));
                LOG.trace("Renaming Field {} with Field {}", key, value);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```

Here is an Example Object.

```
 {
      "id": 123,
      "contactInformation": {
        "contact": {
          "email": "toshiaki_yagi@gmail.com",
        }
      },
      "supportingCustomer": [
        {
          "supportingCustomerName": "JOHN"
        },
        {
          "supportingCustomerName": "JOHN"
        }

      ]

}
```

Here I can rename Id, but having difficulty renaming `supportingCustomerName` and also `contactInformation.contact.email` using `org.json.JSONObject` ? Or is there any other library, i can use to rename keys.Any Help would be appreciated?

My JSON And key are dynamic not fixated.

Comment: You can [use a regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29070952/16653700) to replace the keys.

Comment: @AliasCartellano I can rename high level fields.But How Can i Do it for nested and keys inside List?

Comment: You can replace keys using `str = str.replace("supportingCustomerName","Example");
  System.out.println(str);` on the string of the `jsonObject`.

Comment: What if the another nested object have same name and i don't want to replace that field?Which will not be idea.I would like to only change key which is referred by the client

Comment: Try [iterating through the JSON](https://www.baeldung.com/jsonobject-iteration) and renaming the keys that match the values to change.

Comment: My json is not fixed,i receive different json with diff keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Ended Up using

```
 implementation group: 'com.jayway.jsonpath', name: 'json-path', version: '2.7.0' 


@Override
public DocumentContext renameKey(JsonPath path, String oldKeyName, String newKeyName) {
  List<String> modified =  path.renameKey(json, oldKeyName, newKeyName, configuration.addOptions(Option.AS_PATH_LIST));
  if(logger.isDebugEnabled()){
    for (String p : modified) {
      logger.debug("Rename path {} new value {}", p, newKeyName);
    }
  }
  return this;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain this function please?

Comment: Basically you convert json to jsonpath ,get the path and rename the keys in position based. For example $ is your root, and  $.id is first id  and $contactInformation. contact is another path like that.